# Как правильно оформить тег мета robots

Tags: html

Как правильно оформить тег , что за что отвечает и как правильно оформить для правильной SEO оптимизации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

robots.txt это не тег, а файл который даёт подсказки поисковикам о том, что не стоит индексировать. 
Взгляните инструкцию от яндекса https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html